# Files lost after adding PC to domain

Tags: windows-7, domain

A user has been using their laptop with just a local profile setup.

I added this PC to the domain and logged in as the newly created user on the domain.

Once the profile was created on the PC I logged off and logged on as the domain administrator to the PC.

I moved (yes, I know I should've copied, sorry :( ) files from the local profile to the domain profile.

I logged back into the new domain user account and none of the files I moved from the local profile are there and are no where to be found.

Does anyone know where they could be?

I am running Recuva to see if I can find them that way in the mean time. Any help would be MUCH appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Where did you move these files To/From?  Provide the actual directories if possible.

Comment: I moved from "C:\Users\localprofile\Desktop" to "C:\Users\domainprofile\Desktop".

I did this for all folders, such as: Desktop, Favorites, Documents, Downloads, etc.

Comment: Wasn't able to find the deleted files, but luckily there were "Previous Versions". If anyone knows a solution to finding the deleted files, I would still love to hear it. Thank you.

Comment: So take ownership of the local profile directory as your domain user and view the files?  More specifically log back into the user you used to move them and see if they are there.  The "disappearance" of the files sounds like you simply don't have the permissions to view the files, or worst, you happened to suffer hardware failure when you did this (or you moved them to another location)